# Can python or JS hide video embedded source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, video, video-streaming

I'm doing a video website right now and I would like to hide the embedded source of the video from being seen by beginner programmer. (I know they are no 100% way to hide the video embeded source).

Any experience programmer knows how python or JS can help to do this? or it can't?

Comment: You can't hide your code.  Anything a browser can execute can be seen by any competent programmer.

Comment: just wanna hide from beginner programmer, so is the Obfuscate helps?

Comment: You can't obfuscate HTML.  You can obfuscate javascript.  I wouldn't recommend wasting your time on either because it won't protect you from anything.  Perhaps if you described what you're really trying to protect from, then folks could offer more meaningful and useful answers to your real problem.  This is a case of you asking about a proposed solution to some problem you have rather than you describing the problem you are actually trying to solve.  Please describe the real issue.

Comment: I would like to hide the source of this video on my website <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/81870162?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>   you can see the source is from Vimeo and I would like to hide it or do anything to make beginner programmer not be able to see the source. if I can make it unreadable that's also fine too. but Is obfuscate the right answer?

Comment: Why?  You haven't told us why you want to hide it so we can know what techniques would be the best options.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a beginner and do not know how difficultly different between hiding and not be able to read. I didn't even know that the option of not be able to read is available. So if I want not readable the obfuscate is ok right? and what obfuscate service you recommend? I mean easy to use and secure. Can people re obfuscate? and read the code?

Comment: Yes, people can always read the code.  An obfuscator just makes a little more work to read it.  You still haven't told us why you want to do this?  What are you trying to prevent?  There are probably better ways to solve your problem.

Comment: I do not want people to know that my video source is from Vimeo ^^ and this is very important for the reason I'm sorry to say that it is a secret of business ^^ you have better way to do this? that would be great if you could tell me

Answer (score 3):

For Javascript, hiding code (almost) cannot be done!

However, if your code is sensetive in any manner, try using obfuscators so that the code will not be readable by human eye.

Here are few obfuscation services:

1. Free Javascript Obfuscator: [Javascript Obfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/)
2. Uglify JS: [Uglify JS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)
3. [JSObfuscate to Obfuscate JS/jQuery](http://www.jsobfuscate.com/)
4. JScrambler 3: [JScrambler 3](https://jscrambler.com/)

**UPDATE**: Use this tutorial to get a heads-up: [Improved JScrambler 3 Helps JavaScript And HTML5 Developers Obfuscate Their Code](http://techcrunch.com/2013/04/17/improved-jscramber-3-helps-javascript-and-html5-developers-obfuscate-their-code/)

Comment: Wow that's so cool. Can someone translate it back to human eye language? and my video embedded is in the iframe which i think it is HTML language, how can I apply this JS cool stuff to my Video ?

Comment: here is my Video code: <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/81870162?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

Comment: Obfuscate that code only. Not the rest. Yes in your code you can de-obfuscate your code. But that should happen on server-side (If you have one) or in a util class in client side so that it is not obvious. You need to be ready for the obfuscated string and transform it into what you wanted in the code and keep the trace of the real code on backend. Makes sense?

Comment: so I put this "//player.vimeo.com/video/81870162?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" into the obfuscate and put the result replace this url in the Iframe then I have to de-obfuscate in my python file on the server? is this the concept? so the concept of hiding embeded source is possible?

Comment: Ye, you are a python guy too. Do it this way: Wherever that iframe code resides, run UglifyJS command on it and put it on the project. Then you will have a non-readable code on the client side. I will update my answer with another new tool for obfuscation and also a tutorial on how to do it too :)

Comment: Did you get the answer you wanted to or not? If so, please select the answer so that other members know that you are fine with what you got.

Comment: I'm waiting for the programmer above to discuss first ^^" then I'll do it thank you so much my friend

Comment: Well, team! Your call, is it answered or not. Those have dropped your question I guess.